# Integration three variables

Tags: integration

Could someone tell me how I integrate these kind of equations and in particular the one I wrote down?
The book says that integrating the below expression should give:$$z=y^{n}\left(\frac {dy}{dx}     \right)^{2}$$

$\frac {dz}{dx} = y^{n-1} \frac {dy}{dx} \left( n \left(\frac {dy}{dx}      \right)^{2} + 2y\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}                \right)$

Comment: It's just the product rule.

Comment: But I don't see how I can apply it, and how does it differ from where there is only x and y?

Comment: In general there's no real trick to an integration like this. You just need enough experience to recognize that it looks like it was obtained from the product rule, and then work backwards to figure out what the expression that was differentiated has to be.

Comment: OK, but could you give the solution to the given equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
$$\begin{split}\frac {dz}{dx} &= y^{n-1} \frac {dy}{dx} \left( n \left(\frac {dy}{dx}      \right)^{2} + 2y\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} \right) \\
&= \color{red}{n y^{n-1} \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}\color{blue}{\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} + \color{red}{y^n}\cdot \color{blue}{2 \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}
\end{split}$$

Let $u = y^n$ and $v=\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$.  Then the first term above is $\color{red}{\frac{du}{dx}}\color{blue}{v}$ and the second is $\color{red}{u} \color{blue}{\frac{dv}{dx}}$.  So $z = uv$.

Comment: Your check and upvote are thanks enough. 